# How-To: In angularjs get length of field when ng-model equals undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting, in my controllers.js, to validate a field that is not required, but has validation rules on it when something is entered in. And I cannot just disable the save button if the field is invalid. (per the user, and yes, I know this is very anti-Angular)

The field has a minlength of 2, and a maxlength of 100, and has an ng-pattern that it must pass... IF the user enters anything into it.

So, what I need to be able to do is read the length and value of that field... even when the ng-model for the field = undefined.

So, my method in the controllers.js:

```
var myPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\ \-\.\,\']+$/;
if ((hasValue(vm.MyField) &&
    (vm.MyField.length < 2 ||
    vm.MyField.length > 100 ||
    !myPattern.test(vm.MyField)))) {
        vm.hasError_Overall = true;
        vm.hasError_Certs = true;
        errMsg += errMsg.length > 1 ? "<br />" : "";
        errMsg += "MyField may only contain letters, numbers, spaces, and these symbols: - . , ', and be between 2 and 100 characters long.";
}
```

So, if the user enters, say, 1 character, and clicks the Save button, I want to be able to get into that if statement so I can display the message.

Comment: Have you considered using `ng-pattern` on your DOM input element? You can pass it a regular expression.

Comment: IMHO, I think it is a better approach if you use `ng-maxlength`, `ng-minlength`, `ng-pattern`, and so on for every validation, and then in your _save_ function ask if `$form.$valid`... or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the first condition in the if statement, and handle the case of it being undefined before the if statement. As follows:

```
if(!hasValue(vm.MyField)){
    vm.MyField="";
}
var myPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\ \-\.\,\']+$/;
if (vm.MyField.length < 2 ||
    vm.MyField.length > 100 ||
    !myPattern.test(vm.MyField)) {
        vm.hasError_Overall = true;
        vm.hasError_Certs = true;
        errMsg += errMsg.length > 1 ? "<br />" : "";
        errMsg += "MyField may only contain letters, numbers, spaces, and these symbols: - . , ', and be between 2 and 100 characters long.";
}
```

Comment: Right, but if `vm.MyField === undefined`, then you can't deal with `.length`.

Comment: And if vm.MyField has violated it's ng-minLength rule, then it will be undefined.

Comment: right. That's why you deal with it before the if statement. Then, if it's undefined, we set it to the empty string. And the empty string has length of 0.

Comment: But the field isn't actually empty. It has a character in it. Just not enough characters to keep from violating the rule. The point is that I'm trying to be able to see what is in the ng-model of the input when the validation rules are in violation. So if the rule says "two characters minimum", and there's 1 character in there, I want to be able to see what that character is.

Comment: Got it. So just handle that case before the if statement. Like if vm.myField.length===1 (do something with it) , then proceed forward